# Access C++ function from QML

Tags: c++, qt, function, qml

I'm trying to make a little program with Qt. I have a `main.cpp` with the following code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/tw_looptijden_berekenen/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app->exec();
}

int reken_tijden_uit(){
    return true;
}
```

and I have a `.qml` file:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {

width: 360
height: 360
Text {
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        Qt.quit();
    }
}
}
```

Now, when I click on the `MouseArea`, the program quits. What I want is that it calls the function `reken_tijden_uit` in the `main.cpp` file.

I've googled a lot, and searched on this site to. I've found a couple of answers, but I didn't get one working.

So what code do I put where so I can call the function `reken_tijden_uit` in C++?

Thanks in advance.

---

The header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H
#define EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H

class MyObject : public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject (QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    Q_INVOKABLE int reken_tijden_uit(){
    return 1;
    }
};

#endif // EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include "eigen_function_header.h"

QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));

qmlRegisterType<MyObject>("com.myself", 1, 0, "MyObject");

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/tw_looptijden_berekenen/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app->exec();
}
```

and the QML file:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.myself 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MyObject {
        id: myobject
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            myobject.reken_tijden_uit()
        }
    }
}
```

And the errors are as follow:

```
D:\*\main.cpp:6: error: 'argc' was not declared in this scope
D:\*\main.cpp:6: error: 'argv' was not declared in this scope
D:\*\main.cpp:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token
```

So what did I do wrong?

Comment: please check the following thread this might help you


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709820/communication-between-c-and-qml

Comment: hy, i checked it, but it's not precisly what i want...  i want to add a onclick event  to the mousearea the calls the cpp function. (in javascript is it just reken_tijden_uit(); so how does it works in c++ and qml...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

For any C++ code to be called from QML, it must reside inside a `QObject`.

What you need to do is create a `QObject` descended class with your function, register it to QML, instantiate it in your QML and call the function.
Note also that you have to mark your function with `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Code:

```
#ifndef EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H
#define EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H

#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject (QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    Q_INVOKABLE int reken_tijden_uit(){
    return 1;
    }
};

#endif // EIGEN_FUNCTION_HEADER_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative>

#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include "eigen_function_header.h"

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
    qmlRegisterType<MyObject>("com.myself", 1, 0, "MyObject");

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/tw_looptijden_berekenen/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app->exec();
}
```

QML:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.myself 1.0

Rectangle {

    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MyObject {
       id: myobject
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(myobject.reken_tijden_uit())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best, in a separate .cpp/.h added to your project. Do not forget to include the .h in main.cpp before doing the qmlRegisterType

Comment: alright, i've got a couple of errors, i will post a new answer so it's clear y what the problem is...

Comment: 1) You have twice "QScopedPointer<QApplication>...". Remove the first one 2) Move "qmlRegisterType<MyObject>..." just after the second "QScopedPointer...", i.e. inside main{} 3) do a "console.log(myobject.reken_tijden_uit())" to check that it works (will appear in console in qt creator)

Comment: In the QML? I.e. onClicked: {  console.debug(myobject.reken_tijden_uit())
}

Comment: alrght, i got still errors, and put the console.log on the onClicked in the qml. the errors are as follow:  D:\*\main.cpp:-1: In function 'int qMain(int, char**)':   AND   D:\*\main.cpp:14: error: 'qmlRegisterType' was not declared in this scope   AND  D:\*\main.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token

Comment: and 3 warnings....  1); D:\*\main.cpp:14: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect   2); D:\*\main.cpp:14: warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect   3);D:\*\main.cpp:14: warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect

Comment: alright, i think it's working now, because i've got now 15 errors (A) the first one is: D:\qt\tw_looptijden_berekenen\tw_looptijden_berekenen-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\moc_eigen_function_header.cpp:12: error: #error "The header file 'eigen_function_header.h' doesn't include <QObject>."

Comment: Indeed. Edited for #include <QObject>

Comment: yeeey :P srr, i thought i had it but didn't ;P it works now. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: If you instantiate it in QML, then how can you give this instance access to other objects you have in C++? For example, if an invokable function requires pointers to other objects in your C++ environment, you'd have to give the instance some way of accessing them. How?

Comment: @hellofunk why is function `main` declared as `Q_DECL_EXPORT`?

Comment: @MarkoFrelih see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911387/q-decl-export-keyword-meaning  i can't remember the reasoning in this particular case, but i don't use Qt anymore and this was a couple years ago

Comment: Some important caveat: the function marker with Q_INVOKABLE has to be **public** (or at least, not private, haven't checked for protected).

Answer (score 15):

As an alternative to *qmlRegisterType()* in main.cpp, you can also use context properties to make QObject variables available in QML. (In case you don't require to create different instances of your object with later QML).

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/tw_looptijden_berekenen/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    // add single instance of your object to the QML context as a property
    // the object will be available in QML with name "myObject"
    MyObject* myObject = new MyObject(); 
    viewer.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", myObject); 

    return app->exec();
}
```

In QML, you can then access the object from anywhere in your code with the given name specified in main.cpp. No additional declarations required:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        myObject.reken_tijden_uit()
    }
}
```

You can find more information on QML<->C++ communication possibilities here: https://v-play.net/cross-platform-development/how-to-expose-a-qt-cpp-class-with-signals-and-slots-to-qml

Comment: There is a [flowchart in Qt docs] (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html#choosing-the-correct-integration-method-between-c-and-qml) that helps to decide when better to use _qmlRegisterTypes_ approach and when _setContextProperty_