# Q_DECL_EXPORT keyword meaning

Tags: c++, blackberry-10

`Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)`

What does this `Q_DECL_EXPORT` before `int main(...)` means?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Excerpt from [QT docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html):

> Depending on your target platform, Qt provides special macros that
> contain the necessary definitions:
>
> - Q_DECL_EXPORT must be added to the declarations of symbols used when compiling a shared library.
> - Q_DECL_IMPORT must be added to the declarations of symbols used when compiling a client that uses the shared library.

I haven't check the QT code, but most likely this macro will do following:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
    #define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #define Q_DECL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
    #define Q_DECL_EXPORT
    #define Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

`__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)` tells the linker to import and export (respectively) a symbol from or to a DLL. This is Windows specific.

In your particular case this macro probably could be removed, since `main()` most likely is not part of a library.

Comment: `Q_DECL_EXPORT main()` is necessary when building Qt applications for Android, as native Android applications are loaded as a library from bootstrap Java code. It might have been similar under Blackberry, I don't know.

Answer (score 7):

Its not a keyword, its a macro to encapsulate the different compiler specific keywords to declare a function as being `exported`.

See also [`Q_DECL_EXPORT`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_EXPORT) and [Creating Shared Libraries](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html).

It is usually used with libraries to define those functions which need to be exported from the library, in order to be imported ("used") by other libraries or by executables.

I have not seen this with a `main` function so far, but that could be a blackberry specific thing. On the other hand, this [tutorial](http://hecgeek.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/qt-for-blackberry-playbook.html) does not use the macro with the `main()` function either, so it can probably be removed.