# How to write readable c++ getter and setter in Qt with setter as slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Sorry for the substantial change in the question, see the edits above.

I'm looking for a readable way to write getter and setter in my C++ class using setter as SLOT.

Because my habits I'm used to write getter and setter in the bottom of the class, and with getter near the setter.

Here is how I'm writing now:

```
#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(...);
    ~MyClass();

    void myPublicMethod();

public slots:
    void onEvent(...);

protected:
    int myVal;

//---------------------------------------------- getter and setter
public slots:
    void setVal(int v);
    const int getVal();

};
```

But the answer at the previous question (see the edits) points me out in some overhead (that I didn't care so much about) and unnecessary use of slots for getter (this was what motivated to ask this question) that can be worse for people that uses this class and see some un-motivated slot for getters.

## EDIT: substantial change in the question. It was:

Title: Qt getter & setter as public slot, bad idea?

I'm writing all getter and setter as public slot. Actually I use only setter as slots but write them one near each other enhance readability.

Is this a bad idea? Any side effects?

Comment: Qt does this too. For example [`QLineEdit::setText(const QString &)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlineedit.html#text-prop) is a slot. You can also check the [`QLabel` setter slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlabel.html#public-slots).

Comment: @thuga I'd say the question is primarily about getters.

Comment: @Angew The question states `Actually I use only setter as slots`. So I'd say it's more about setters.

Comment: @thuga Well, it says "I am *writing* both as slots, but only *using* setters as such."

Comment: @Angew Good point. Also good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have no side effect except extra code generation. Each slot adds some data to class meta information + add some code to moc generated files.

Also you can mark setters with Q_SLOT macro. And place both in same place.

Comment: @nkint If you want your public setter slot declaration to be next to your public getter function declaration, you can just use the [`Q_SLOT`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#Q_SLOT) macro for your setter, as stated by Dimitry.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's a bad idea because it's pointless, and as such it provokes a "wtf" (which is usually a sign of bad code).

It's pointless because Qt signals can't return values, and the sole purpose of a getter is to return a value. So it makes no sense to make getters slots.

I'm talking about getters only, of course. Setters are perfectly fine (and useful) as slots.

Also, there is some memory overhead with each metamethod a class defines (and maybe some performance overhead when establishing connections, not sure). Not much, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov The only difference between a slot and a normal member function is that it can be called through a connection (i.e. by emitting a signal). It will react to that signal by returning a value, which goes where...?

Comment: Author talks about marking public members as slots. I posted an answer. I don't undestand, why you are talking about signals and return values.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Because good code is not only valid, but also meaningful (otherwise it's hard to maintain). And a getter as slot is not meaningful, because there is no meaningful way to use it *as a slot* (i.e. connect to it). Yes, the connection will succeed, but it cannot ever do anything useful.

Comment: Making getters as slots - it is an analogue of callbacks. You may request some information via signal with argument-pointer and getter slot will fill necessary data. It's calling syncronization with sognals and slots. This is a rare practice, but sometimes it's ok.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Yes, a function with an output parameter can make sense as a slot. I don't think it fits the usual definition of a getter, but it's a related point.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a method to be accessible from QML you don't need to make it a slot. You can simply use the Q_INVOKABLE macro as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501367/12172630).