# How can I load a list of defines into QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Here is the the thing, I have a header file with a list of defines, defining string constants. I'm doing my interface with QML. I was wondering if there is any way to import those defines so that I can reference from QML.

Comment: Don't think it's possible to export macro defines to `QML`. it's processed in the preprocessor...Why not use `readonly` property for the constants.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50281612/904422

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089196/how-to-access-c-enum-from-qml